# Insert text in specific lines of a file? with special characters

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, quoting

I know this has been answered several times, but I can't figure out how to use it for my project.

I have several php files and want to add a new string between line 11 and 12.
this is the string I want to add

```
exec('/var/www/scripte/autostandby.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

I guess this is the way to go (for a single file,for multiple I will use *.php instead of file):

```
sed '12i\
exec('/var/www/scripte/autostandby.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
' file.php
```

what I get:

```
[1] 29234                                                                                                            
bash: $');\n': command not found
```

so I guess bash just runs the exec command or something.

how do I add a "long" string containing spaces and stuff like ; ) , ' which seems to mess up the command?

p.s.: adding " " or ' ' doesn't trick the pony.

**Bonus:**

I also need to "append" something in line 11 from this:

```
exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh');
```

to this

```
exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

If possible for all .php files. It's always line 11; the only thing that changes is "taketv.sh" to "abc.sh" or anything like that.

It is the first occasion that " '); " are shown in this combination, so I tried it with something like this (only for 1 file as a test):

```
 sed -i "s/');/ > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');" TakeTV.php
```

I guess I need to use what mikeserv said. I tried but it didn't work.

```
sed -i 's\                                                                             
'\'');/'\''/'\'' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');'\''
```

My plan was to set the "old word" and "new word" as a closed quote, guess I didn't apply it right!

Comment: while we are at it: i also need to append something in line 11 from this:

exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh');

to this

exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &'); IF possible for all .php files. its always line 11, the only thing that changes is "taketv.sh" to "abc.sh" or anything like this.

Comment: You quoted too much! Basically you need to double up the quotes which are supposed to be quotes. So if you want a string to be `this ain't your average string`, you wrap it and double the inner quotes: `'this ain'\''t your average string'`. see? when all of those quotes are removed from the string the `'` through `n` is one quoted string, the following `\'` is one escaped apostrophe, and everything following that is the rest of the string. in any case, you don't have to do all of that work - you've already got most of what you need on line 11 - edit it, print it, edit it again. i made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use several types of quotes or escape them:

```
sed -i "12iexec('/var/www/scripte/autostandby.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');" *.php
```

Bonus:

```
 sed -i "s|exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh');|exec('/var/www/streams/taketv.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null \&');|"
```

Comment: perfect, just had to remove the "/" directly infront of "exec"

Comment: i edited a little bonus to the question. would be really nice if you could help me. i didnt want to start a new question, because its pretty much the same topic.

Comment: I edit the answer for the bonus. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed '12i\
exec('\''/var/www/scripte/autostandby.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &'\'');
' file.php
```

You have to quote the whole thing.

Your problem is you're trying to insert quotes from within a quoted string. It is doable, but you have to quote the quotes.

```sh
command 'begin quoted arg'\''
   close quotes
   backslash quote the apostrophe
   open quotes again
'\'' end quoted arg'
```

---

You can do without all of that though:

```sh
sed -e'11s|.)[^)]*$| >/dev/null 2>/dev/null&|p' \
    -e'11s|www.*sh|www/scripte/autostandby.sh|' <in >out
```

Still if you do use `a`ppend or `i`nsert or `c`hange, it really is best to do so as you attempted to do in your question. Those commands are specified to require a newline separator between the commands and the *text* arguments they take.

Comment: i am not allowed to upvote yet, so i THANK YOU right here :)

Comment: @SchnitzelKopf - that will do just fine, and thanks for doing so.